# How do I assert that a given jq expression is returning only one result?

Tags: json, select, jq, assert

Say I'm getting an API response back that looks somewhat like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "foobar",
      "description": "it's the foobar 1000 baby!"
    },
    {
      "name": "another_thing",
      "description": "acme 1000 whizbang machine"
    }
  ]
}
```

I pipe this object to the filter `.results[] | select(.name == "foobar").description`, but I'm not super confident I've written the `select()` filter completely correctly. How can I assert that the `select()` filter is functioning as intended, and returning exactly 1 result?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "assert" and/or what results you want in the various possible cases.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there would be multiple values in the output?

Comment: This won't work if you really pass the full object to the filter given. You probably want something like `.results[] | select(…)` or `.results | map(select(…))`; the latter allowing you to check the length of the extracted array.

Comment: @peak by "assert" I mean something similar to an assert in e.g. Python - the program should crash/raise an error if the assumed invariant (in this case that the output of `select()` is exactly one object) is false.

Comment: @knittl whoops - I extracted this question from a bit of source code I wrote for work and accidentally omitted `.results[]`. will fix now.

Answer (score 1):

The `select()` filter emits a (possibly empty) stream of JSON objects, *not* a single array of JSON objects. Therefore while we can use `length` to do such an assertion, we have to be clever about it:

```
[select(.name == "foobar").description]  | if length == 1 then .[] else "\(length) results produced" | error end
```

Of course you can do whatever you like instead of raising the error.

The way this works is by wrapping the stream of objects returned by the `select()` filter in an array, so that the subsequent `length` filter doesn't operate on each object individually and instead operates on the list of objects. If the assertion passes, we unwrap the array again for the caller's convenience with `.[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array to start with, it's probably more straightforward to use the `map(select(f))` pattern:

```
.results
| map(select(.name == "foobar") | .description)
| if length == 1 then first else error("expected exactly one result") end
```

alternatively:

```
.results
| map(select(.name == "foobar") | .description)
| select(length == 1)[0] // error("expected exactly one result")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an "assertion"-style filter that you could use to avoid collecting all the results:

```
def assert_one(s):
  reduce s as $x (null;
    if . == null then {emit: $x, n:1}
    else "assertion error: more than one"|error
    end )
  | select(.n == 1).emit 
  // ("assertion error: none"|error);
```

Usage example:

```
[{ name: "foobar", description: "yes"},
 { name: "foobar", description: "maybe"} ]
| assert_one(.[] | select(.name == "foobar" and has("description")).description)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an expression which is guaranteed not to produce MORE than one result, use `first/1`.

If you want an expression which is guaranteed to produce exactly one result, assuming there are no errors preventing at least one result, you could perhaps use `first` in conjunction with `//`.  In this case, of course, you'd have to specify what value you wanted in case the underlying query produces no results.

Here's an example:

```
first(select(.name == "foobar" and has("description"))).description // "no description provided"
```

A simpler alternative that might nevertheless be acceptable is:

```
first(select(.name == "foobar").description // empty) // "no description provided"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various functions to filter your input stream in a way that only certain results or a given number of them will be kept while others are being discarded.

To (silently) discard a second and all subsequent results (i.e. getting only the first one or nothing), use `first(f)` as [suggested  by @peak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76179261/2158479). For the first n results there is the generalized `limit($n; f)` filter which provides you with all results until the nth one, i.e a stream of up to n items, thus `limit(1; f)` would act like `first(f)`. Note that these filters (correctly) produce nothing if the stream was empty in the first place. You can test against this case using `isempty(f)` which produces a boolean as expected.

To actively assert an exact (or a minimum or a maximum) number of results, i.e. take action if that fails, without collecting all items into a memory-consuming array just to query its length, you could count the size of the stream using `reduce`, and act upon evaluation of that result. Here's a function that takes a number, an input stream which is reproduced (unaltered, i.e. as a stream) if the amount matches, and another filter that is produced instead if the counting fails. (Replace `==` used for exact matches with one of `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` to open up the upper or lower bounds.)

```bash
def assert_n($n; f; g): if reduce f as $_ (0; .+1) == $n then f else g end;
```

Applied to your test case:

```bash
# produces exactly one result, namely "it's the foobar 1000 baby!"
assert_n(1; .results[] | select(.name == "foobar").description; error("not one"))

# errors out as select(true) happens to produce too many (>1) results
assert_n(1; .results[] | select(true).description; error("not one"))

# errors out as select(false) happens to produce too few (<1) results
assert_n(1; .results[] | select(false).description; error("not one"))
```

You can further generalize this approach by e.g. providing the counting result to a custom function.

```bash
def assert_c(c; f; g): if reduce f as $_ (0; .+1) | c then f else g end;

# produces an odd number of results, or errors out otherwise
assert_c(.%2 == 1; .results[] | select(.name == "foobar"); error("was even"))
```